# How Can I Commit,Update,Add And Remove Files In Xcode To SVN?

Tags: ios

I am a beginner in ios.How can i perform all the svn operations of eclipse in xcode?Do i have to use any applications from the app store for this?I want to commit,update,revert,delete.

Answer (score 0):

See the document [Source Control Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/_index.html) and the 2013 WWDC video [Understanding Source Control in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=414)